# Emails I send keep getting into recipient's Spam folder in Gmail

Tags: gmail, email, spam-prevention

I have a personal domain and I use a mail account on it (it's not Gmail). Recently, all the emails I send (personal and business messages, not bulk) keep getting into the recipients Gmail Spam folder (I checked with several recipients).

Why is that and what can I do?

More info:

- I checked and my domain is not in the blacklist.
- When looking at the message in the Spam folder, it states  "It's similar to messages that were detected by our spam filter".
  However, this is a personal message I wrote to someone - not a newsletter or a bulk message.
- My sites and mail server are on a shared hosting service. But until recently I didn't have this problem.

Comment: Look for the bulk sender guidelines on https://support.google.com/mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, seems I SOLVED the problem for now. I'm posting here for anyone who encounters the same issue.

What I did was:

1. Created PTR record in my domain's DNS settings
2. Enabled DKIM in my domain's hosting
3. Created SPF record in my domain's DNS settings (see explanation and examples at https://www.sonicwall.com/en-us/support/knowledge-base/170504417772166)
4. Created DMARC record in my domain's DNS settings (see explanation and examples at https://www.sonicwall.com/en-us/support/knowledge-base/170504796167071)

You can use https://mxtoolbox.com/domain to check domain health and problems with DNS.

Good luck!